# Как динамически проверять вводимые символы в input при использование маски

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть вопроса заключается в работе с плагином, и русском номере телефоне.

Я использую этот плагин: [jQuery mask plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html)

У меня настроена на инпут след. маска:

```
$('.PhoneNumber').mask('+7 (000) 000-00-00')
```

Тоесть маска настроена на международный формат. Бывают слепые пользователи, которые начинают вводить номер телефона с цифры 8, и не видят, что маска в инпуте автоматически подставляется и начинает писать значение с :

```
+7 (8..)
```

В результате история заканчивается тем, что слепой пользователь до конца вводит цифры, не смотря на экран, и получается последнюю цифру не вводит, так как маска ее не воспринимает, и мы получаем не верный номер телефона.

Вопрос заключается в том, как можно сделать так, что бы при первом вводе 8рки маска эту цифру не воспринимала, но если пользователь второй раз ввел 8 - то уже воспринимала. Если пользователь вводит любые цифры отличные от 8 то пропускать все символы.

Может кто то работал с плагином и сможет помочь решить вопрос?

Comment: А номер не может действительно начинаться с +7 8.... ? Тогда кто заметил +7 впереди и вводит реальный номер, начинающийся с 8, недопечатает первую 8... Может... к кнопке отправки докрутить проверку первого числа. Если оно совпадает с 8 - не отправить, а красными буквами вывести запрос подтверждения, что номер точно правильный.

Comment: Эта ошибка будет в таком ключе как вы описали только тогда, когда пользователь решит ввесли городской номер, ито случай очень будет редким. Поэтому нужно сделать так как я описал. При первом вводе 8 надо пропустить. если ввели еще раз то уже отобразить

Comment: изначально поле ввода пустое. поэтому тот кто начнет с 8 увидет на экране что у него только появилась возможность ввода после нажатия первой 8ки

Answer (score 1):

$(...)`.one` запускает функцию только один раз. А `.slice()` разрезает строку в указанных местах. В данном случае slice`(0,1)` — это первый символ.

```js
$(document).one('input', '#PhoneNumber', function(){ 
  if( this.value.slice(0,1) == '8' ){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/^8/,'');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#send', function(){
  if( $('#PhoneNumber').val().length < 11 /*или какая там длина должна быть...*/){
    alert('Кажется введенный номер слишком короткий!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="PhoneNumber">

<button id="send">Отправить</button>
```

Здесь есть минус - если сотрет и решит еще раз набрать - уже не сработает.

P.s. у меня там `#`id, а у вас `.`class, не перепутайте)